# Signature, publisher and company checking using sigcheck application

Tags: java, kernel, digital-signature

When I execute sigcheck from command prompt I get proper result. But when I execute with the help of code, result is different.

**Result When executed from command prompt :**

```
C:\>sigcheck.exe -vt "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Sigcheck v2.42 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

c:\program files\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe:
        Verified:       Signed
        Signing date:   5:53 AM 1/29/2016
        Publisher:      Google Inc
        Company:        Google Inc.
        Description:    Google Chrome
        Product:        Google Chrome
        Prod version:   50.0.2633.3
        File version:   50.0.2633.3
        MachineType:    32-bit
        VT detection:   1/55
        VT link:        https://www.virustotal.com/file/f65dda151e7e52baa5619a08
1d687479a9d65d2f3d67f2481d6c60b85de11080/analysis/
```

**Result When executed from code:**

chrome.exe                    3024 Console                    1      4,452 K Running

Here is the standard output of the command:

```
Hello in if LOOP
    Verified:   Unsigned
    Publisher:  n/a
    Company:    n/a
    Verified:   Unsigned
    Publisher:  n/a
    Company:    n/a
```

Code:

```
public void verifysignature(String filepath) {

    String s = null;

    try {
        filepath= "\""+filepath+"\"";
        System.out.println("This is file path " + filepath);

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\sigcheck.exe -vt " +filepath); //

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(" hello " +stdInput);

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {

                        /*System.out.println(s + "This is the S");*/

                        if(s.contains("Verified:") || s.contains("Publisher:") || s.contains("Company:"))
                        {
                            sb1.append(s).append("\n");
                            System.out.println("Hello in if LOOP");
                            /*System.out.println(s);*/
                            System.out.println(sb1);
                        }

    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        sb.append(s).append("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the filepath also as a part of your command.
 String cmd="sigcheck64.exe -h someapp.exe";
 Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);